# Concrete5.6.3.4 Page & Area permissions

Tags: permissions, concrete5

I'm trying to update a site from 5.6.3.2 to 5.6.3.4 but running into a problem with the page permissions not correctly applying to area's/blocks.

- Advanced permissions are on.
- Permissions are applied by hierarchy.
- Subpage permissions are inherited from the page's permissions.

As user1 I can see every part of the site and can edit. But as a guest some pages (the blocks in de content area of that page) are not visible. Adding new blocks to the area on the page doesn't work either.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9">
 <div class="main-content">
  <h1><?php echo $c->getCollectionName(); ?></h1>
  <?php $mainContent = new Area('Contentfield'); ?>
  <?php $mainContent->display($c); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Only the main area doesn't work, sidebar, topnav, menu, footer area's are rendered and shown as always.

I did see something is updated in the area permissions as of 5.6.3.3 (- Fixed problem with area permissions) but do I need to change something in my templates/blocks?

Or is there a more general fix for this problem?

gr moonshard

Comment: Perhaps you have custom permissions defined on the area or the blocks that it contains that allow anyone to view?

Comment: Permissions for this block are currently dependent on the area containing this block. -- Nothing is filled in, everything is none. 

The following area permissions are inherited from an area set in Default defaults. -- These have the correct perms for 'view area'. Admin, Guest

Comment: But the page Defaults have none set and I've set them to manual with the correct perms pasted in. And it seems to work now. Strange behaviour.